# How to search for an image on screen in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, image-recognition

I want to search for an image on screen using C# or other .NET languages(like powershell). Something like i give an image location in the file system and the code consider the whole screen as an image and search the image in the file system in the big image(the screen) then returns the image position on screen. I can't find this kind of things in the .net classes.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little. What do you mean by an image being on the screen? How/where is it shown?

Comment: @Darin
I edited my question, please read it again to see if you understand my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a pretty specific problem, which is why you won't find it in the .NET Framework. You should break down your problem in smaller pieces:

**Load image from file on disk**

Use [System.Drawing.Image.FromFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx).

**Acquire an image of the screen, i.e. a screen shot**

Use [System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx):

```
Bitmap CaptureScreen()
{
    var image = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    gfx.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    return image;
}
```

**Find image inside image**

See answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472467/how-to-find-one-image-inside-of-another).

Comment: "You should break down your problem in smaller pieces" +1 for that :)

Answer (score 0):

i have made a program which used a lib i coded in c# which will return the value of x and y of a small image inside a bigger image (screenshot) you can see all the details here https://www.nulled.io/topic/22223-an-advanced-image-search-library-saeedsearchdll/

Comment: Link is dead...