# Is there a way to check if one image is a part of another image and return it's position in PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, position

I've got source image https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/ZRor and an image to compare with the source https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/ZRol

Is there a way in PHP to check if the source contains this image and return it's left and top position related to the source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect / calculate if a small pictures is present inside a bigger picture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679451/how-can-i-detect-calculate-if-a-small-pictures-is-present-inside-a-bigger-pict)

Answer (score 0):

Try out Imagick::compareImages function, http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compareimages.php

It will "Returns an array containing a reconstructed image and the difference between images."

That should work.