# Compare an image with another image PHP

Tags: php, image

How can I find out how many times an image appears in another one with php, so I can calculate how much money I will have if I sell the items from the print screen of my backpack.

**For example,** this is my backpack:

[image: Backpack]

This is the item I want to compare:
[image: Knight amor]

If a user submits this image of the backpack, comparing only the Knight Armor (where each one is worth 5,000), the result should be 15,000.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect / calculate if a small pictures is present inside a bigger picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679451/how-can-i-detect-calculate-if-a-small-pictures-is-present-inside-a-bigger-pict)

Comment: I already saw this post and it really did not help me

Comment: im not surprised, php was never designed with such tasks in mind.

Comment: You are making it a fairly complex problem by using a screenshot of the game in the beginning. If you'd directly read from the process memory, you'd find item IDs and amounts in there (though backpacks used to be represented in a nested structure in that game client, I think it was a Red-Black-Tree). You could also capture and decrypt network packets sent to the client, yielding the same information. Just don't DLL inject or start manipulating stuff.

Comment: idk man, the game went on to use a new anti cheat that has been banning several players, the Battle-Eye anti cheat,