# How to get coordinates of cropped image from original

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find one image inside of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472467/how-to-find-one-image-inside-of-another)

I have two images. One is the original (let's say it's 500 x 800 pixels. The other is a cropped image (let's say 300 x 200 pixels) takend from the original.

What I'm looking for is a way using c# to look at both images and find the coordinates of the cropped image within the original.

Hope that makes sense?
Any help appreciated.