# AForge Image Processing exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, bitmap, aforge

I'm trying to use the algorithms of [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html) library seen in [this little example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472467/how-to-find-one-image-inside-of-another) to find an image inside an image, the code of that example works perfectlly ...but to finish the comparission (find 50x50px in 1920x1080px) it takes forever, so I would like to resize the images to gain speed...

From this:

```
Dim sourceImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\1.bmp")
Dim template As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\2.bmp")
```

To this else:

```
Dim sourceImage As Bitmap = ResizedBitmap1
Dim template As Bitmap = ResizedBitmap2
```

The problem is that when I try to use the methods with my resized Bitmaps I get an exception of: `Unsupported pixel format of the source` with this StackTrace:

> AForge.Imaging.UnsupportedImageFormatException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147024809   Message=Unsupported pixel format of the source
>   or template image.   Source=AForge.Imaging   StackTrace:
>          en AForge.Imaging.ExhaustiveTemplateMatching.ProcessImage(Bitmap image,
>   Bitmap template, Rectangle searchZone)
>          en AForge.Imaging.ExhaustiveTemplateMatching.ProcessImage(Bitmap image,
>   Bitmap template)
>          en WindowsApplication9.Form1.Test() en c:\users\administrador\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsApplication9\WindowsApplication9\Form1.vb:línea
>   22
>          en WindowsApplication9.Form1._Lambda$__1(Object a0, EventArgs a1) en c:\users\administrador\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsApplication9\WindowsApplication9\Form1.Designer.vb:línea
>   0
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
>          en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry
>   tme)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          en Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>          en Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>          en Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)
>          en WindowsApplication9.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) en 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:línea 81
>          en System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          en Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

So there seems to exist a difference between the Bitmaps instanced by the `Bitmap` Class than the Bitmaps that I return with my `ResizeImage` function.

This is the code that I'm using

```
Imports AForge.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

    ' A Desktop Screenshot, 1920x1080 px. resolution.
    Dim DesktopScreenshoot As New Bitmap("C:\1.png")

    ' A cutted piece of the screenshot, 55x57 px. resolution.
    Dim PartOfImageToFind As New Bitmap("C:\2.png")

    ' create template matching algorithm's instance.
    Dim sourceImage As Bitmap = ResizeImage(DesktopScreenshoot, Percent:=40.0R) ' Bitmap.FromFile("C:\1.bmp")
    Dim template As Bitmap = ResizeImage(PartOfImageToFind, Percent:=40.0R)   ' Bitmap.FromFile("C:\2.bmp")

    ' (set similarity threshold to 92.1%).
    Dim tm As New ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.921F)
    ' find all matchings with specified above similarity.

    Dim matchings As TemplateMatch() = tm.ProcessImage(sourceImage, template)
    ' highlight found matchings.

    Dim data As BitmapData =
        sourceImage.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height),
                                           ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, sourceImage.PixelFormat)

    For Each m As TemplateMatch In matchings

        Drawing.Rectangle(data, m.Rectangle, Color.White)

        ' do something else with matching
        MessageBox.Show(m.Rectangle.Location.ToString())

    Next m

    sourceImage.UnlockBits(data)

End Sub

' By Elektro
'
''' <summary>
''' Resizes an image by a size percentage.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Bitmap">Indicates the image to resize.</param>
''' <param name="Percent">Indicates the percent size.</param>
''' <returns>Bitmap.</returns>
Private Function ResizeImage(ByVal [Bitmap] As Bitmap,
                             ByVal Percent As Double) As Bitmap

    Dim [Width] As Integer = ([Bitmap].Width) \ (100.0R / Percent)
    Dim [Height] As Integer = ([Bitmap].Height) \ (100.0R / Percent)

    Dim NewBitmap As New Bitmap(Width, Height)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(NewBitmap)
        g.DrawImage([Bitmap], 0, 0, [Width], [Height])
    End Using

    Return NewBitmap

End Function

End Class
```

Comment: you might want to examine some of the other [Bitmap] properties like PixelFormat and resolution to make sure you are not accidentally changing one to a format AForge cannot handle (RTM for that).  Also, your Resize function will only work well on a square image (messes up the AR).  If it is more rectangular, you have to scale it.

Comment: @Plutonix I'm really a newbie playing with images, the problem logically was about pixelformat but I didn't understood exactlly what to do to fix it, just I've fixed it with an `Dim NewBitmap As New Bitmap(Width, Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)` when resizing it, feel free to convert your comment into an answer to markit as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be with this:

```
Dim NewBitmap As New Bitmap(Width, Height)
```

The default values for things like `PixelFormat` or resolution may be something AForge cannot handle (the docs would tell what they can and cannot handle).   Also, glancing at the SO link, it **looks like** (tl;dr) AForge has a Resize function (`ResizeBicubic`) which obviously might be expected to produce a bitmap it can handle.

Ignore my AR comment - I was thinking you wanted to resize to a Max or fixed H or W, which would require scaling the other.