# Unsupported Pixel Format of source or template image. AForge Imaging

Tags: c#, exception, aforge, imaging

I am getting the following Exception at `ProcessImage(bitmap1, bitmap2)`;

```
Unsupported Pixel Format of source or template image
```

and this is my code:

```
public static double FindComparisonRatioBetweenImages(
    System.Drawing.Image one, System.Drawing.Image two)
{
    Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(one);
    Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(two);

    ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0);
    TemplateMatch[] matchings = null;

    matchings = tm.ProcessImage(bitmap1, bitmap2); // Exception occurs here!

    return matchings[0].Similarity;
}
```

I have also passed `managedImage` from the below code into the method, but it still gives error:

```
UnmanagedImage unmanagedImageA = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(bitmap1);
Bitmap managedImageA = unmanagedImageA.ToManagedImage();
UnmanagedImage unmanagedImageB = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(bitmap2);
Bitmap managedImageB = unmanagedImageB.ToManagedImage();
```

1. I have passed Images randomly from my computer, they all give exception.
2. I have passed Blank Image edited in paint into the method,it still give exception.
3. Also checked, jpeg, png, bmp formats, nothing work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586979/aforge-image-processing-exception

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [`ExhaustiveTemplateMatching`](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/17494328-ef0c-dc83-1bc3-907b7b75039f.htm):

> The class implements exhaustive template matching algorithm, which performs complete scan of source image, comparing each pixel with corresponding pixel of template.
>
> The class processes only grayscale 8 bpp and color 24 bpp images.

So, those are the image formats you must use.

As requested, to convert to a specific pixel format, you can do this:

```
public static Bitmap ConvertToFormat(this Image image, PixelFormat format)
{
    Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, format);
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(copy))
    {
        gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, copy.Width, copy.Height));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

The one you would use is [`System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Can i convert pixel Format of anyimage

Comment: Sure, hold on a second.

Comment: tried to convert it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016406/converting-bitmap-pixelformats-in-c-sharp
but it gives exception saying graphics can not be created from indexed pixel format

Comment: I have used "PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed"

Comment: Well, I'd go for `Format24bppRgb` since `Format8bppIndexed` only allows for up to 256 colors.

Comment: @dbc I wanna use 16 bit grayscale image. Can I use it? I am trying to stitch image in Accord.net project having 16 bit images. I know it supports upto 8 bit. But my question is can I use it for 16 bits grayscale images???