# QImage contains smaller QImage

Tags: qt, qimage

How can I check if a large QImage contains a smaller QImage?

Let's say the large QImage contains a picture of a cat (the cat in this image has the same size as the cat in the following small Qimage) and the small QImage is the cat. Now I want to know if the small QImage (the cat) is in the large QImage.

Comment: This doesn't seem Qt-specific, no?  Are you looking for something different than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472467/how-to-find-one-image-inside-of-another?

Comment: yes same problem. but the accapted answer is not accaptable for me. Searching corners is no valid approach for my case.

Comment: If there are hidden requirements, you might be explicit what they are.  There are also other solutions not involving corner detection to that question but I don't know if any of them work given your constraints.